# Discord.py - ' becomes \\' and I can't decode it back again

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I have a discord bot which allows people to name a card from a card game like so: `!card card name`
The bot then constructs an image URL from the name and posts that to the channel. For now, it's super simple and does no verification or anything, but it does have one issue I'd like to fix, which is that it can't deal with apostrophes.

If the card name includes an apostrophe (ex. "Card's Name") my bot creates the URL using %27. The card db however replaces the apostrophe with a "-". Unfortunately, I don't receive an apostrophe, so string.replace("'", "-") does not work.

My IDE displays the string correctly while it is in the command array, and as soon as I retrieve it from there it looks like so: `Card\\'s Name`
I'm assuming that it always is escaped, but the IDE displays it in a parsed fashion when it isn't the raw string.

I want to decode/parse this so that I can turn it into "card-s-name", but nothing I've tried works.

urllib.parse.decode "can't decode string", string.replace("\", "") didn't do anything and so I'm kinda stuck for now.

How do I turn "card\\'s" into "card-s"?

Here's the code as I use it right now:

```
def get_card_url(command):

  card_name = ''

  for string in command:
    string = urllib.parse.unquote(string)
    string.replace("'", "-")
    if card_name != '':
        card_name += '-'
    card_name += string.lower()

  return "https://fiveringsdb.com/bundles/card_images/" + card_name + ".png"
```

The card where I run into the error is called "Kitsuki's Method" and the url is posted to the channel as https://fiveringsdb.com/bundles/card_images/kitsuki%27s-method.png instead of https://fiveringsdb.com/bundles/card_images/kitsuki-s-method.png

I hope that helps clear up any remaining confusion.

Comment: `card\'s` is what you see after the escape character has done its work. `card\\'s` seems to be your initial string, so `"card\\'s".replace("\\'", "-")` should work

Comment: Sorry, I always see two backslashes, but SO escaped one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my ipython notebook, it works well.

```
"card\'s".replace("\'", "-")
```

output is `card-s`

[image]

Edit:

If you are confused about what the var is ,you can print it.And then,use the Escape character to the characters needed.

For example:
[image]

**Update:**
str.replace() return a new str,but it do not change the old str. So you need to let a var equal to the new str, then use the var.

```
def get_card_url(command):

    card_name = ''

    for string in command:
        string = urllib.parse.unquote(string)
        string = string.replace("'", "-")
        if card_name != '':
            card_name += '-'
        card_name += string.lower()

    return "https://fiveringsdb.com/bundles/card_images/" + card_name + ".png"
```

test:
[image]

**But** I still can't reproduce your mistakes about `%27`

Comment: He said his string in the ide looks like `Card\\'s Name` so in my opinion he was just confused with what the string is.

Comment: @StamKaly I am confused about his description.Maybe you are right.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that SO escaped one of my backslashes, so in the lower part of my text, it didn't look the same as in the beginning, even though it should've.

Comment: So, when I print it, it is printed as `Card's`. However, when I then output my string, it becomes `card%27s-name`.

I tried using `string.replace("\\\'", "-")` but that didn't change the result either.

Comment: @MarkZ, Output to where? Can you give us some example in code,and show us what you get when run your code?

Comment: I added the code to the question. It is output to a discord channel, as I stated in the description. My bot takes a name and should create the proper url to link the image in discord.

Comment: I can't reproduce your mistakes.I use `["Kitsuki's", "Method"]` to be input of your code, and the return is `"https://fiveringsdb.com/bundles/card_images/kitsuki's-method.png"`. Sorry ,maybe i still don't understand your question.Is my input wrong?

Comment: a) the output should be `"https://bla/kitsuki-s-method.png"` with **no** apostrophe. b) huh. I get the URL containing %27 - so what else is different? I'm using Python 3.6.1 on a Manjaro Linux, Kernel 4.10.

Comment: I add `string = string.replace("'", "-")` to your code ,and get the right answer. See my update in my answer.But I still did not get %27 in the return.I'm using python3.4.3 ,ipython1.2.1 on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Well, now I feel right silly. I completely missed that string.replace was not in-place. Thank you, that fixed my problem!